# Deleting records after Insert Into statement in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have the below statement to move records from staging table (dbo.tblImportBCCDataStaging) to production table (dbo.tblImportBCCData) based on the time spent in the staging table (which is 10 mins) and if the job  doesn't exists in the production table. So far the insert statement works, but how can I delete the inserted records afterward?

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.tblImportBCCData (JobNo, Zip, Country, Copies, AWB, DelvCode, OPSCode)
 SELECT     JobNo, Zip, Country, Copies, AWB, DelvCode, OPSCode
 FROM         dbo.tblImportBCCDataStaging AS t
 WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                      (SELECT     JobNo
                        FROM          dbo.tblImportBCCData
                        WHERE      (JobNo = t.JobNo)))
 GROUP BY JobNo, Zip, Country, Copies, AWB, DelvCode, OPSCode, DateStamp
 HAVING      (DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(DateStamp), GETDATE()) > 10);
```

Comment: Can't you just delete from staging where exists in production?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a temp table but I would use the following.  Based on your query it appears `JobNo` is your unique identifier and likely has an index. In that case:

```
Delete T
From dbo.tblImportBCCDataStaging T
Join dbo.tblImportBCCData P On P.JobNo = T.JobNo
```